# javascript find() returns true however item is not included in the array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, date, datetime

I have a simple helper function to find date in the array of dates based on given day, in this function I convert day name to day number, and then I want to find all dates with the given day number:

```
function findDatesByWeekday(date, weekdayArr) {
    const dayNumbers = weekdayArr.map(({ day }) => textToDayNumber(day));
    return dayNumbers.find(n => {
        console.log(
            `n: ${n}, getDay: ${new Date(date).getDay()} result: ${new Date(
                date
            ).getDay() === n} date: ${date}`
        );
        return new Date(date).getDay() === n;
    });
}
```

However, it does not find Sundays, although the result of return statement is true.

```
n: 6, getDay: 6 result: true date: Sat Oct 16 2021 12:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)
n: 6, getDay: 0 result: false date: Sun Oct 17 2021 12:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)
n: 0, getDay: 0 result: true date: Sun Oct 17 2021 12:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)
n: 6, getDay: 6 result: true date: Sat Oct 23 2021 12:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)
n: 6, getDay: 0 result: false date: Sun Oct 24 2021 12:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)
n: 0, getDay: 0 result: true date: Sun Oct 24 2021 12:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)
n: 6, getDay: 6 result: true date: Sat Oct 30 2021 12:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)
n: 6, getDay: 0 result: false date: Sun Oct 31 2021 12:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)
n: 0, getDay: 0 result: true date: Sun Oct 31 2021 12:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)
```

What is more, it generated unwanted output as I was asking for five dates, and it returned five Saturdays instead of three Saturdays and two Sundays.

```
0: Sat Oct 16 2021 12:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time) {}
1: Sat Oct 23 2021 12:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time) {}
2: Sat Oct 30 2021 12:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time) {}
3: Sat Nov 06 2021 12:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time) {}
4: Sat Nov 13 2021 12:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time) {}
```

With every other week day it works just fine, it's just the Sunday, so I am quite sure that it comes down to zero being a falsy value, and I know how to fix it function below works as intended

```
function findDatesByWeekday(date, weekdayArr) {
    const dayNumbers = weekdayArr.map(({ day }) => textToDayNumber(day));
    return dayNumbers.includes(new Date(date).getDay());
}
```

I just want to understand why :)
Thanks

Hi is a start of the edit of the question as you have requested. You are right, I am sorry I should have included the context by default. I do not use filter as I use this helper in the filter method as a predicate

```
newHighlightedDays = benchmark.filter(date =>
   findDatesByWeekday(date, weekDaysWithTime))
.filter((_, i) => i < lessonCount);
```

weekdaysWithTime is an array of objects like these:

```
{
day: "Piątek",
time: {h: 12, m: 30}
},
{
day: "Sobota",
time: {h: 12, m: 30}
},
{
day: "Niedziela",
time: {h: 12, m: 30}
}
```

and textToDayNumber is this function:

```
export function textToDayNumber(text) {
    switch (text.toLowerCase()) {
        case "niedziela":
            return 0;
        case "poniedziałek":
            return 1;
        case "wtorek":
            return 2;
        case "środa":
            return 3;
        case "czwartek":
            return 4;
        case "piątek":
            return 5;
        case "sobota":
            return 6;
        default:
            throw new Error("invalid day name");
    }
}
```

I am sure that this is not a timezone issue as it compares not dates per se, but a weekday name parsed to day number with the date from react-day-picker, here is an example of benchmark array to reproduce the code:

```
Tue Oct 19 2021 12:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time) {}
Wed Oct 20 2021 12:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time) {}
Thu Oct 21 2021 12:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time) {}
Fri Oct 22 2021 12:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time) {}
Sat Oct 23 2021 12:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time) {}
Sun Oct 24 2021 12:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time) {}
Mon Oct 25 2021 12:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time) {}
Tue Oct 26 2021 12:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time) {}
Wed Oct 27 2021 12:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time) {}
Thu Oct 28 2021 12:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time) {}
Fri Oct 29 2021 12:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time) {}
Sat Oct 30 2021 12:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time) {}
Sun Oct 31 2021 12:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time) {}
Mon Nov 01 2021 12:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time) {}
Tue Nov 02 2021 12:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time) {}
Wed Nov 03 2021 12:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time) {}
Thu Nov 04 2021 12:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time) {}
Fri Nov 05 2021 12:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time) {}
Sat Nov 06 2021 12:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time) {}
Sun Nov 07 2021 12:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time) {}
Mon Nov 08 2021 12:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time) {}
Tue Nov 09 2021 12:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time) {}
Wed Nov 10 2021 12:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time) {}
Thu Nov 11 2021 12:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time) {}
Fri Nov 12 2021 12:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time) {}
Sat Nov 13 2021 12:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time) {}
Sun Nov 14 2021 12:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time) {}
Mon Nov 15 2021 12:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time) {}
Tue Nov 16 2021 12:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time) {}
Wed Nov 17 2021 12:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time) {}
```

Thank you! :)

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): _"Include just enough code to allow others **to reproduce the problem**. For help with this, read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."_

Comment: _"so I am quite sure that it comes down to zero being a falsy value"_ - It is, but your `.find()` version returns an actual boolean (`new Date(date).getDay() === n`) and not a number

Comment: Are you sure this isn't a timezone issue and not a day issue?

Comment: @Andreas `.find` accepts a callback that should return a boolean value. When you return true it means the that item should be included in the result. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_find.asp
However find return only the first items where the condition is true.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understood the question:

> and then I want to find all dates with the given day number:

`find` returns only the first matching item. Use `filter` to return an array of matching items.

```
function findDatesByWeekday(date, weekdayArr) {
    const dayNumbers = weekdayArr.map(({ day }) => textToDayNumber(day));
    return dayNumbers.filter(n => {
        console.log(
            `n: ${n}, getDay: ${new Date(date).getDay()} result: ${new Date(
                date
            ).getDay() === n} date: ${date}`
        );
        return new Date(date).getDay() === n;
    });
}
```